# Built in speakers volume control not working, it is either mute or too loud

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, volume-control, pipewire

I cannot adjust the volume properly because it would be mute or too loud even at 1%. I'm using a laptop with built in speakers of probably 4-6 internal speakers. I noticed that when using alsamixer+pipewire-pulse, there are PGA playback output controls that I can adjust and the volume controls works well on that, (especially on PGA1 and PGA30).

[image: alsamixer screenshot]

Other approach that I use is by changing the playback profile from **HiFi quality music** to **Pro Audio** can solve this problem temporarily but i have to manually reactivates this profile every time after suspending the laptop.

Does anyone have solution how to make the master volume, speaker volume respects the PGA1 and PGA30 playback slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this happens when the laptop has 4 speakers, my device is LENOVO Yoga Pro 7 14IRH8 and somehow it cannot controls the volume of the built in speaker properly (it can only mute and unmute even though we use the slider).

Current workaround is by configuring `["api.alsa.soft-mixer"] = true` in `/usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua`, [source](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/3269).

Or if you are using pipewire-media-session (defaults to 22.04 Ubuntu), you can try `/usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/alsa-monitor.conf` and edit the `api.alsa.soft-mixer = true`