# ASUS Q505UA Built-in Speaker Volume Control

Tags: sound, alsa

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10, but this issue spans 3 releases.  Sound plays through my built-in speakers but the volume is either full (100%) or muted.  There are no noise issues when any sound is playing.  When headphones are connected, volume control is normal and there are also no noise issues.

I have found similar issues via search including this forum, but nothing is exactly this issue.  None of the suggested fixes for the similar issues have any effect, except for the soft mixer fix in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487563/built-in-speakers-volume-control-not-working-it-is-either-mute-or-too-loud). However, changing to the ALSA soft mixer, disables the headphone jack.

This is a dual boot computer, sound works perfectly in Windows 11.  Fastboot on or off has no discernible impact on this issue.

The sound device is an ALC295 configured with a built in microphone, 2 speakers, and a combo headphone/mic jack.

What is a good next step short of diving headlong into the Intel HDA sound architecture details and the driver code to find the one thing to be fixed?